# Calling backing bean method based on URL

Tags: jsf-2

I'm having one problem in JSF. Is there any way to call backing bean's method based on the URL? When using Struts, I could achieve it by `structs-config` and action class. When I migrate from Struts to JSF, I am facing this problem.

Comment: This will help you: http://balusc.blogspot.in/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) which greatly improves JSF navigation. Enabling you to use nice understandable, bookmarkable REST urls.

I you use Servlet 3.0 then you just have to add PrettyFaces jar to your web app,
annotate your managed bean with page mappings, and select actions for particular mappings:

```
import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLAction;
import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLMapping;
import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLMappings;

@ManagedBean(name = "pageViewBean")
@URLMappings(mappings = {
    @URLMapping(id = "myAction",
    pattern = "/page/myAction", // URL mapped to jsf file
    viewId = "/page.xhtml"),    // jsf file
    @URLMapping(id = "myAction2",
    pattern = "/page/myAction2", // URL mapped to jsf file
    viewId = "/page.xhtml")})    // jsf file
public class PageViewBean
{

    @URLAction(mappingId = "myAction") // action for URL /page/myAction
    public void myAction()
    {
        ...
    }


    @URLAction(mappingId = "myAction2") // action for URL /page/myAction2
    public void myAction2()
    {
        ...
    }
```

Thats all.

Comment: PrettyFaces is a great tool, we are using it with PrimeFaces and it has solved many architectural problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `<f:event type="preRenderView" />` , it will be called each time your page will be rendered, put it above your `<h:head>` tag

For example:

```
<f:event listener="#{myBean.myAction}" type="preRenderView" />
<h:head>
...
</h:head>
<h:body>
...
```

And in your bean :

```
public void myAction(ComponentSystemEvent event){
    ...
}
```